# SQL Server Indexed Views vs Oracle Materialized View

Tags: sql-server, oracle, view, indexed, materialized

I know materialized view and I'm using it. I have never used indexed views but I will. What are the differences between them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server’s indexed views are always kept up to date. In SQL Server, if a view’s base tables are modified, then the view’s indexes are also kept up to date in the same atomic transaction.

Oracle provides something similar called a materialized view. If Oracle’s materialized views are created without the `**REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT**` option, then the materialized view is not modified when its base tables are. So that’s one major difference. While SQL Server’s indexed views are always kept current, Oracle’s materialized views can be static.