# Indexed or Materialized view replicating on SQL Server DB from Oracle DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle, materialized-views, indexed-views

Goal is for the most simple/nimble way to have a number of tables in a production Oracle DB, replicated on a SQL Server DB (for reporting purposes) and as close to  real time.

Currently, I'm doing something like:

```
insert into SQL_Svr_tab select * from openquery(ORA_DB, 'select * from table')
```

Only, there's a `where` clause in the query on the `ORA_DB` as needed... ruining as job in SQL Server Agent.

My thought/hope is to use either a materialized view in Oracle but the actual object should reside on SQL Server. Thought [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220979/sql-server-indexed-views-vs-oracle-materialized-view) and some other preferences stir me to have it to rather have Indexed View on SQL Server side that would pull from Oracle.

Comment: Netier Materialized Views on Oracle nor Indexed Views on SQL Server will help.  Check out [Change Data Capture Service for Oracle by Attunity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-service-for-oracle-by-attunity)

Comment: Why don't you use sql server replication?